# Installing Node js manually vs with package managers

Tags: javascript, node.js

I installed Node.js on Mac last year by just downloading it from nodejs.org. However, i have noticed that it is usually installed via some package managers like Homebrew(bad way) and NVM(good way). Question 1: Should i uninstall current Node.js and install it via NVM(which i don't even have)? Question 2: Is switching between Node version common? And why would someone do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using NVM is a good idea indeed!!. There may be different projects that use different versions of NodeJs. In that situation, a library like NVM would be pretty helpful else you have to uninstall the old version and install the new one. You know how hard it is to uninstall and reinstall a new one each time you want to have a new version. Moreover if you want to try some new feature that is shipped in a newer version of Nodejs, you have to go through the installation/uninstallation process again.

So using NVM would create a sandbox like environment where one version on Node won't mess with another one.

Long story short, NVM would be helpful.After you install NVM, it's just a matter of doing `NVM install 'nodeversion'` and `NVM use 'nodeversion'` to use a particular version of Node.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you could be working on different projects which are based on different versions of node. nvm could help in this case.

It’s also very helpful if you want to verify whether your application works on different versions of node or not.

In general it’s nothing different with python2/3, different version of JDK, etc. You can stick with your current installation and switch to nvm only if it’s necessary. You will know when you need it.